# Is it legal for a spouse to gamble against each other at home in the US?

Tags: united-states, gambling

Is it legal for a spouse to gamble against each other at home in the US, with no third-party involved?

Comment: Are you saying something like "hey [spouses name], I bet you $10 the [sports team] wins today"? Or something different? This is probably dependent on the State that the two reside in (or are in when they place the bet)...

Comment: As a practical matter, the chance of anyone trying to enforce an anti-gambling law under those circumstances would be small.Who would file a complaint, or proceed on it? If the only witness is the spouse, any testimony might well be excluded on that ground alone.